# Problems using the window.navigator object to get info back on vistors browser

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get information back on the vistors browser to my website. 
However the return I get for each parameter is 'undefined'.

The code I am using is below (this is referenced as external JS doc in the HTML head):

```
function navigator(){
    alert("YOUR COMPUTER INFO SIR: \n\nBrowser Code Name: " + navigator.appCodeName + "\nBrowser Name: " + navigator.appName +  "\nBrowser Version: " + navigator.appVersion +  "\nCookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "\nPlatform: " + navigator.platform +  "\nUser-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "\nUser-agent language: " + navigator.systemLanguage );
}
```

I am calling the function in the HTML body as:

```
<input type="button" onclick="navigator()" value="Click Me to get your computer Info!"/>
```

And the data is returned as:

```
YOUR COMPUTER INFO SIR: 

Browser Code Name: undefined
Browser Name: undefined
Browser Version: undefined
Cookies Enabled: undefined
Platform: undefined
User-agent header: undefined
User-agent language: undefined
```

Any ideas?

Update:
Thanks, Renamed the function as suggested to navigatorInfo and got data returned as follows:

Browser Code Name: Mozilla
Browser Name: Netscape
Browser Version: 5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/536.29.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.4 Safari/536.29.13
Cookies Enabled: true
Platform: MacIntel
User-agent header: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/536.29.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.4 Safari/536.29.13
User-agent language: undefined.

However I am using a Safari browser and the Browser returned is Mozilla....

UPDATE:
OK, got it, thanks for the help....
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Comment: You've shadowed the global `navigator` object by creating a function with the same name. Pick another name, or use `window.navigator.appName`, etc.

Comment: @RobW is correct you are overwriting the namespace of navigator by calling it inside of a function of navigator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`navigator` is an object that exists in browsers. You must rename your function to something other than `navigator` like `navigatorInfo` or something.

Comment: Renamed the finction naviagatorInfo and got some data as follows:

Comment: Go ahead and hit the check next to my answer when you can - if you think it's correct, that is.

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it, thanks for the help....
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html